# Implementating Analytical Hierarchy Process with ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-statistics

I want to use the AHP in arcmap 10.2. I have tried using the arcscript available from

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13764

Which was designed for Arcmap 9.2.

I was able to get as far as selecting the input rasters, but when I attempted to proceed with the next step I was met with the following error message:

> Run-time error '339':
>
> Component 'COMDLG32.OCX' or one of its dependencies is no correctly
>   registered: a file is missing or invalid

Ideally, I would like to know how to get this script to work in arcmap 10.2.

Answer (score 2):

This tool seems to have been overhauled and is now called [extAhp20 - Analytic Hierarchy Process for ArcGIS](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bb3521d775c94b28b69a10cd184b7c1f):

> The provided extension is an update of the old extAHP extension (AHP
>   1.1) which was available for download from the old ArcScripts site. This update also computes criteria weights according to the well known
>   Analytic Hierarchy Process (AHP) but integrates a criteria hierarchy.
>   It is a powerful tool for the creation of suitability maps (spatial
>   planning, risk mapping and more)! Manual and some example files
>   included. Allows for up to 15 criteria.

It also says (with my bolding):

> Developed using VS 2010. Developed for ArcGIS 10.1. **Works also in
>   10.2**. Tested in Windows 7 and 8. A 'Spatial Analyst' extension is required! Information on technical requirements is provided in the
>   manual which will be unpacked and copied to the installation folder by
>   the setup program.